# Nested classes and collections vba

Tags: vba, class, collections, nested

I am trying to create a collection of a company's employees. Each employee has a name, age, manager and a team reporting to him/her. As the manager is an employee itself, I want to use the same class as the object. For the team I use an array of the same class object. If an employee do not have a team this should be null. Also, for the top level manager who does not have a manager, the manager should also be null.

This is how i defined the CEmployee class:

```
Private pName As String
Private pManager As CEmployee
Private pTeam() As CEmployee
Private pAge As Integer

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = pName
End Property

Public Property Let Name(Value As String)
    pName = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Manager() As CEmployee
    Manager = pManager
End Property

Public Property Let Manager(Value As CEmployee)
    pManager = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Team() As CEmployee
    Team = pTeam
End Property

Public Property Let Team(Value As CEmployee)
    pTeam = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Age() As Integer
    Age = pAge
End Property

Public Property Let Age(Value As Integer)
    pAge = Value
End Property
```

Then adding employees into a collection:

```
Dim Employees As Collection

Dim v_Emp As CEmployee

Set Employees = New Collection

Set v_Emp = New CEmployee
Set v_Man = New CEmployee
Set v_Team = New CEmployee

v_Man.Name = "John Doe Top Manager"
v_Man.Age = 42
v_Man.Team = Null
v_Man.Manager = Null
```

First of all, setting Team and Manager to Null crashes, so I know this does not work. But what I am really wondering is if this is a good approach? I am very new to classes and collections and would appreciate any guidance and directions.

Thanks!

/Olof

Comment: `Null` doesn't mean what you think it does. When "nulling" an object reference in VBA, you use the `Set` keyword and you assign to `Nothing`, e.g. `Set v_Man.Team = Nothing`.

Comment: Once you have working code, feel free to put it up for peer review on [codereview.se] - validating whether your approach is good or not is beyond the scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: I have actually added you question to codereview here . Take a look, both the question and the 2 answers are interesting -
 https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/190049/collections-of-classes-in-vba

Comment: Thanks you, I'll take a look at the post!